# How to fill a pointer array without a function call and from a macro?

Tags: c, macros

I have a small recursive AST as follows:

```
enum ABC
{
    A,
    B,
    C
};

typedef struct abc_t
{
    enum ABC kind;
    union {
        struct a_
        {
            int x;
        } a_;
        struct b_
        {
            int y;
        } b_;
        struct c_
        {
            struct abc_t **array;
        } c_;
    } u;
} abc_t;
```

To simplify the constructions, I define fill macros:

```
#define ABC_SET_A(n)    (abc_t) { .kind = A, .u.a_ = { n } }
#define ABC_SET_B(n)    (abc_t) { .kind = B, .u.b_ = { n } }

const abc_t bar = ABC_SET_A(5);
const abc_t foo = ABC_SET_B(2);
```

However, I don't know how to fill the "c_" branch of my AST with a macro. I would like to arrive at this result:

```
const abc_t test = ABC_SET_C({ABC_SET_B(4), ABC_SET_A(3), ABC_SET_B(2)});
// or
const abc_t test = ABC_SET_C(ABC_SET_B(4), ABC_SET_A(3), ABC_SET_B(2)); // With variadics arguments
```

The goal would be to have an immutable array of `abc_t` that would represent a set of pre-built structures, something like:

```
const abc_t pre_builds[] =
{
    ABC_SET_A(10),                            // pre_builds[0]
    ABC_SET_C({ABC_SET_A(8), ABC_SET_B(4)}),  // pre_builds[1]
    ABC_SET_B(23)                             // pre_builds[2]
    ...
};
```

I don't know how to handle a recursive structure for a such as macro, especially for an array in this case.
How do I do it?

Comment: `abc_t **array;` why is this a double pointer? Is `abd_t *array` not enough? Why is `struct` keyword missing from it?

Comment: It's true, I forgot the `struct` in my code, I'll edit it. However, a recursive structure, in C, must refer to itself via a pointer, so I need a double pointer: one to refer to the structure and another to specify that it is an array. Isn't that the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First fix your `ABC_SET_A` and `ABC_SET_B`. You don't initialize `int` with braces like `int var = { 1 };` , you initialize `int` like `int var = 1;`:

```
#define ABC_SET_A(n)    (abc_t){ .kind = A, .u.a_ = n }
#define ABC_SET_B(n)    (abc_t){ .kind = B, .u.b_ = n }
```

Doing your `ABC_SET_C` is easy. As you have array of pointers in your structure, you can do this:

```
#define ABC_SET_C(...)  (abc_t){ .kind = C, .u.c_ = (abc_t*[]) __VA_ARGS__ }
const abc_t pre_builds[] =
{
    ABC_SET_A(10),                            // pre_builds[0]
    // note - as this is array of pointers, I added & to get the pointer
    ABC_SET_C({&ABC_SET_A(8), &ABC_SET_B(4)}),  // pre_builds[1]
    ABC_SET_B(23)                             // pre_builds[2]
};
```

The `{` `}` braces are not special to preprocessor anyway and not parsed by it. I would prefer:

```
#define ABC_SET_C(...)  (abc_t){ .kind = C, .u.c_ = (abc_t*[]) { __VA_ARGS__ } }
const abc_t pre_builds[] =
{
    ABC_SET_A(10),                            // pre_builds[0]
    ABC_SET_C(&ABC_SET_A(8), &ABC_SET_B(4)),  // pre_builds[1]
    ABC_SET_B(23)                             // pre_builds[2]
};
```

If you want to get rid of writing `&` in front of every `ABC_SET_*`, then you can overload the macro on number of arguments and insert them per each argument. I find it not worth the effort, but it may be implemented like this for up to 3 arguments:

```
#define ABC_SET_A(n)    ((abc_t){ .kind = A, .u.a_ = n })
#define ABC_SET_B(n)    ((abc_t){ .kind = B, .u.b_ = n })
#define ABC_SET_C_1(_1)        &_1
#define ABC_SET_C_2(_1,_2)     &_1, &_2
#define ABC_SET_C_3(_1,_2,_3)  &_1, &_2, &_3
#define ABC_SET_C_N(_1,_2,_3,N,...)  ABC_SET_C##N
#define ABC_SET_C(...)  (abc_t){ .kind = C, .u.c_ = (abc_t*[]) { \
        ABC_SET_C_N(__VA_ARGS__,_3,_2,_1)(__VA_ARGS__) \
    } }

const abc_t pre_builds[] = {
    ABC_SET_A(10),                            // pre_builds[0]
    ABC_SET_C(ABC_SET_A(8), ABC_SET_B(4)),  // pre_builds[1]
    ABC_SET_B(23)                             // pre_builds[2]
};
```

Personally I don't like writing `(abc_t)` a compound literal in macro variable initialization. They make somethings like `abc_t *arr = (abc_t[]){ 
ABC_SET_A(8) }` impossible. I prefer leaving writing the `&(abc_t)` if needed to the user, so that others will know what is a pointer and what is not a pointer, so they know when and how the memory is allocated, what is the storage duration of the memory, etc. It also makes the macro easy to work in C++ and C99. Like this:

```
#define ABC_SET_A(n)    { .kind = A, .u.a_ = n }
#define ABC_SET_B(n)    { .kind = B, .u.b_ = n }
#define ABC_SET_C(...)  { .kind = C, .u.c_ = __VA_ARGS__ }
const abc_t pre_builds[] = {
    ABC_SET_A(10),                            // pre_builds[0]
    ABC_SET_C((abc_t*[]){ &(abc_t)ABC_SET_A(8), &(abc_t)ABC_SET_B(4) }),  // pre_builds[1]
    ABC_SET_B(23)                             // pre_builds[2]
};

// it also allows for something like the following naturally to work:
abc_t *make_me_visible_in_debugger[] = {
    &(abc_t)ABC_SET_A(8),
    &(abc_t)ABC_SET_B(4)
};
const abc_t pre_builds2[] = {
    ABC_SET_A(10),                            // pre_builds[0]
    ABC_SET_C(make_me_visible_in_debugger),  // pre_builds[1]
    ABC_SET_B(23)                             // pre_builds[2]
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is a function generally preferred for this kind of task, over a macro (if we don't take into account the fact that it has to be constant here)?

Comment: I believe there is a generall tendency to prefer `static inline` function instead of macro functions. However, as noted, a function call is not a constant expression, so macros are used everywhere where a constant expression is needed.

Comment: Note C11 [§6.7.9 Initialization ¶11](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p11): _The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces._ So the braces in `int var = { 1 };`  are permitted by the standard, though I'd grant you the option to use them is rarely exploited.